# No prompt for signing a certificate for Cordova windows app

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to create and install a Cordova windows application by using the command-line tools. When running `cordova run windows --device`, the shell shows this text:

```
Before installing this app, you need to do the following:
        - Install the signing certificate
Administrator credentials are required to continue.  Please accept the UAC
prompt and provide your administrator password if asked.
```

The problem is that **there's no prompt**. Cordova seems to sit there, waiting for me to accept the prompt, but I can't do anything but press `ctrl-c`. How to get the prompt or otherwise get aroung the problem?

My environment: Windows 8.1 Enterprise, VS Express 2013, Cordova 6.0.0. Project created with:

```
cordova create hello
cd hello
cordova platform add windows
cordova build windows
cordova run windows --device
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not dig in to the details, but

```
cordova run windows --device -- --phone
```

seemed to do what I needed: it successfully installed the application to the attached phone.

Comment: and how to run on the emulator?