# Getting error while running Ionic cordova app for windows platform

Tags: angular, windows, cordova, ionic3, cross-platform

While running a ionic cordova app for windows platform I am getting an error as "Install the signing certificate".
I have referred to : [No prompt for signing a certificate for Cordova windows app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741960/no-prompt-for-signing-a-certificate-for-cordova-windows-app)
But this did not solve the issue, can anyone please help to resolve the issue?

Error Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I would use Visual Studio 2017 for creating windows-platform apps using Cordova, it includes all the stuff you need to get started easily and you'll get much more detailed errors descriptions too.

Comment: I want to do this using the command prompt or shell is there any other way to achieve the same.